# Tomcat 7 not starting in Eclipse 4.2 (timeout). How to get more verbose output?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7

I am really struggling with an Eclipse project where Tomcat is giving me timeout. I thought at first this might be a mistake I did in some project configuration, so I reverted to an earlier version of my code. However this is still giving the same error! When I try to start a new project (Spring MVC) along the existing one, the new one seems to work fine and (if I disable the non-working one) the server now starts.

My question really is: How can I get more verbose output or log from Tomcat? The server telling me "it was unable to start within the time limit" does not really help me. Most of the solutions I have found for this kind of problem arent really solutions either, but "remove the server and add it again" or "Delete your eclipse workspace and start over again", etc. Is it really not possible to get Tomcat 7 to do some proper debug-logging to tell me whats going on?

The following is all the output I get:

```
mai 03, 2013 1:17:45 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
mai 03, 2013 1:17:46 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:kneip' did not find a matching property.
mai 03, 2013 1:17:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
mai 03, 2013 1:17:46 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
mai 03, 2013 1:17:46 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 666 ms
mai 03, 2013 1:17:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
mai 03, 2013 1:17:46 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
mai 03, 2013 1:17:57 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Fri May 03 13:17:57 CEST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
INFO : org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO : org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext - Successfully resolved class for [net.krg.kneip.AppConfig]
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO : org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@4cb8a2a9: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,appConfig,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.importAwareProcessor,camel,jmsConfig,activeMq,pooledConnectionFactory,jmsConnectionFactory,applicationContextProvider]; root of factory hierarchy
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In the end you need to increase the timeout limit for startup of tomcat from eclipse.

- Double click on the Server ("Apache Tomcat") within the "Servers" view.
- Open the "Timeouts" Section
- increase "Start (in seconds)" to 120

(*this does not lead to more log information, but it should solve your problem.*)

[image: increase timeout limt]

Comment: Unfortunately all this does is make me have to wait 2 minutes for the same error message.

Comment: Are you able to start tomcat with your project on command line (without eclipse)? And how long does this start from command line take?